# NumberFormatException thrown by Integer.parseInt

Tags: java, numberformatexception

Hey Im taking coding lessons at school but the teacher does not explain that well so we have to look for info online which I did, but I was not able to find the error in my code, can you help me please?

```
char end='s';     
do{
    System.out.println("Tipo de boleto");
    char boleto = (char) System.in.read();
    switch (boleto){
        case 'a':
          System.out.println("El boleto cuesta $120.00");
          System.out.println("Otro boleto (s/n)?");
          end = (char) Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
          continue;
    case 'n':
          System.out.println("El boleto cuesta $75.00");
          System.out.println("Otro boleto (s/n)?");
          end = (char) Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
          continue;
    case 'i':
          System.out.println("El boleto cuesta $60.00");
          System.out.println("Otro boleto (s/n)?");
          end = (char) Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());;
          continue;
    default:
          System.out.println("Error" );
          break;
    }
}
  while (end == 'n');
```

**Exception**

```
    run: Tipo de boleto a El boleto cuesta $120.00 Otro boleto (s/n)? 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" at 

java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592) at 

java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) at 
asjidbhahsjksbd.Asjidbhahsjksbd.main(Asjidbhahsjksbd.java:16) Java Result: 1 

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

Comment: Can you please add what error/warning you have?

Comment: run:
Tipo de boleto
a
El boleto cuesta $120.00
Otro boleto (s/n)?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at asjidbhahsjksbd.Asjidbhahsjksbd.main(Asjidbhahsjksbd.java:16)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)

Comment: @user65185 please edit your answer instead of adding to comments.

Comment: your entrada.readLine() is having blank space "" so its throwing exception.

Comment: instead of entrada.readLine use System.in.read() to get s or n. And its good if you use break instead of continue.

Answer (score 5):

See, you are trying to *parse* `""` as an *Integer* whichwill throw `NumberFormatException`. You have to check for `null` and `isEmpty()` in this order and then try to parse the string as an integer.

Comment: @TheLosMind
Some code would be nice as the OP is quite novice.

Comment: Why do you think he wants to parse an integer, after asking the user to type in "s" or "n"?

Comment: @ajb - Agreed. But that is the flaw in his program :). His error, well that is because of what I 've mentioned.

Comment: @user65185 - Like *ajb* says, why are you trying to read a String, parse it as an integer and then convert it into a char?.

Comment: I just want to read the char and give an answer according to what the user  says, and then ask again untill he says no.

Answer (score 0):

you should replace continue statement with a break. putting continue will skip the current iteration and the while condition will not be evaluated.

Comment: You should add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exception in this line , i think you are getting `""` **blank** String from `readLine()` method

```
 end = (char) Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
```

So Do like this

```
String input=entrada.readLine();
if(input!=null && !input.equals(""))
{
 end = (char) Integer.parseInt(input);
}
```

I suggest you to use [google guava libraries](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) which is having a utility function

```
Strings.isNullOrEmpty(inputString)//Checks String for both null and empty
```

**Update** 
As @ajb suggested :

If you want to convert **s** and **n**  into character than don't use your code snippet

instead of Parsing an Integer

Use

```
char c=input.charAt(0);
```

Comment: Why do you think he wants to parse an integer, after asking the user to type in "s" or "n"?

Comment: I am not thinking anything  , it's written in his own code snippet that he is trying  to parse an integer . and the Exception shows it that Exception occured due to parsing a blank string

I am also unable to understand without translation what he wants to say in this line  [ Otro boleto ] , So ignoring  that I have given my answer

Comment: And he's trying to parse the integer and convert the integer to a character.  His code snippet is obviously wrong.

Comment: P.S. I don't know what a _boleto_ is either, but I do know what _sí_ and _no_ mean.

Comment: Its a program that shows the cost of the ticket(boleto) the user asks for, and then it asks again untill the user says no.

Answer (score 0):

This does not do what you think it will:

```
end = (char) Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
```

This line reads a string.  It then assumes the string is a *number*, and determines the number.  If the user actually enters `"s"` or `"n"`, it throws an exception, because `"s"` and `"n"` are not numbers.  The number is then treated as the ASCII value of a character.  The result is that the loop will test whether the user types in the string `"110"`, since 110 is the ASCII value of the character `n`.

There are several ways to fix this; here's one:

```
end = entrada.readLine().charAt(0);
```

This returns the first character of whatever line the user types in.  This is a sloppy solution because it doesn't work if the user hits ENTER on an empty line (it will throw an exception).  Better:

```
String answer = entrada.readLine();  
if (answer.isEmpty()) {
    end = 'n';        // treat an empty string like 'n'
} else {
    end = answer.charAt(0);
}
```

Also, I think the `while` might be wrong.  `while (end == 'n')` means the program will loop back if the user enters `n`, which I think is the opposite of what you want.

P.S. There are other errors that I didn't catch, that others have pointed out; using `continue` is wrong--use `break` to leave the `switch` statement.  And reading one character with `System.in.read()` is a problem, because the user will type in a character, but the character won't get into the program until the user types ENTER, and then `readLine()` will get the rest of this first line, instead of asking for another line.  But I usually don't use `System.in.read()` so I'm not completely sure what this does without trying it.

Comment: I get an error with this, the words getChar are unerlined in red.

Comment: charAt, not getChar.  Sorry.  I need to stop answering questions late at night.