# Android calculator app stops when pressing any of operator buttons

Tags: android, calculator

I have used the following code to develop a simple calculator app:

```
package com.example.sparsh.newcalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView1;
    Button button0;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;
    Button button5;
    Button button6;
    Button button7;
    Button button8;
    Button button9;
    ImageButton buttonPlus;
    ImageButton buttonMinus;
    ImageButton buttonMultiply;
    ImageButton buttonDivide;
    String a, b;
    int result, result2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        button0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button0);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
        button7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
        button8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
        button9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
        buttonPlus = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);
        buttonMinus = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonMinus);
        buttonMultiply= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonMultiply);
        buttonDivide = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonDivide);
        a = " ";
        b = " ";
        result=0;
        result2=1;

        button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a = a+button0.getText().toString();
                textView1.setText(a);
            }
        });

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            a = a + button1.getText().toString();
            textView1.setText(a);
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a = a + button2.getText().toString();
                textView1.setText(a);
            }
        });

        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a = a + button3.getText().toString();
                textView1.setText(a);
            }
        });

        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a = a + button4.getText().toString();
                textView1.setText(a);
            }
        });

        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a = a + button5.getText().toString();
                textView1.setText(a);
            }
        });

        button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a = a + button6.getText().toString();
                textView1.setText(a);            
            }
        });

        button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a = a + button7.getText().toString();
                textView1.setText(a);
            }
        });

        button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a = a + button8.getText().toString();
                textView1.setText(a);
            }
        });

        button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a = a + button9.getText().toString();
                textView1.setText(a);
            }
        });

        buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //textView1.setText(" ");
                result  =   Integer.parseInt(a) + result;

                textView1.setText(Integer.toString(result));
            }
        });

        buttonMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //  textView1.setText(" ");

                result = Integer.parseInt(a) - result;
                textView1.setText(Integer.toString(result));
            }
        });

        buttonMultiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //textView1.setText(" ");

                result2 = Integer.parseInt(a) * result2;
                textView1.setText(Integer.toString(result2));
            }
        });

        buttonDivide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //textView1.setText(" ");

                result2 = Integer.parseInt(a) / result2;
                textView1.setText(Integer.toString(result2));
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Pressing the number buttons work fine, but whenever I press any of the operator buttons (like plus, minus, multiply, divide), the app stops.
I have not been able to know what the problem is. Please help!

The logcat in 'Debug' mode has following info:

```
02-12 12:29:03.728 8994-8994/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-12 12:29:03.784 8994-8994/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
02-12 12:29:03.856 8994-9002/? E/zygote: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
02-12 12:29:03.856 8994-9002/? I/zygote: Debugger is no longer active
02-12 12:29:03.878 8994-9002/? W/zygote: Suspending all threads took: 22.488ms
02-12 12:29:03.944 8994-8994/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
02-12 12:29:04.303 8994-9016/? D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline

                                                 [ 02-12 12:29:04.401  8994: 9016 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9a926e80, tid 9016
02-12 12:29:04.459 8994-8999/? I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=9KB, data=18KB
02-12 12:29:04.459 8994-8999/? I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=9KB, data=18KB
02-12 12:29:04.459 8994-8999/? I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
02-12 12:29:04.460 8994-8999/? I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=9KB, data=36KB
02-12 12:29:04.460 8994-8999/? I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=9KB, data=36KB
02-12 12:29:04.460 8994-8999/? I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
02-12 12:29:04.460 8994-8999/? I/zygote: JIT allocated 71KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
02-12 12:29:04.460 8994-8999/? I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
02-12 12:29:04.595 8994-9016/? I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
02-12 12:29:04.595 8994-9016/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-12 12:29:04.595 8994-9016/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
02-12 12:29:04.714 8994-9016/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa50e6160: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
02-12 12:29:04.753 8994-9016/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa50e6160: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa501b6f0)
02-12 12:29:04.863 8994-9016/com.example.sparsh.newcalculator D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa50e6160: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa501b6f0)
02-12 12:29:07.446 8994-8994/com.example.sparsh.newcalculator I/Choreographer: Skipped 174 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-12 12:29:12.710 8994-8994/com.example.sparsh.newcalculator D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-12 12:29:12.711 8994-8994/com.example.sparsh.newcalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                            Process: com.example.sparsh.newcalculator, PID: 8994
                            java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 666"
                                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:597)
                                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
                                at com.example.sparsh.newcalculator.MainActivity$11.onClick(MainActivity.java:147)
                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I have not implemented the 'equals' button for now. But pressing the operator buttons should display the result.

Comment: **`Android calculator app stops when pressing any of operator buttons`** you need to show crash log with question

Comment: @Nilesh, added the logcat info in the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292154/numberformatexception-thrown-by-integer-parseint

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&hs=GFq&channel=fs&dcr=0&q=java.lang.NumberFormatException:+For+input+string:+%22+666%22+at+java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:597)+at+java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:64&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF1cLc55_ZAhUMso8KHdibBTEQBQgjKAA&biw=1600&bih=727

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is failing is because of the `" "`space before the `666` as per your stack trace. You need to ensure that your String variable `a` is an empty string i.e `""` not a string with a space i.e `" "`. Try using `a.trim()` to remove whitespaces

Comment: Removing space while initializing "a" and "b" resolved this issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse " 666" which contains an empty space, thus resulting in a `NumberFormatException`. You have to make sure that the string you are parsing doesn't have any characters that are not digits. Use [`String.trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) to remove any leading/trailing whitespaces, but before trying to parse the values, also make sure that the value you are parsing is not an empty string by using [`String.isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()).

Comment: Removing space while initializing "a" and "b" resolved this issue. Thanks a lot!